# Problema haciendo un Cast (HashTables)

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy tratando de programar una Tabla de Hash, y estoy teniendo problemas con un cast. No me permite hacer un cast pues me marca el error. También tengo una clase Lista programada que implementa los NodosDoble (ver abajo) y no sé si tal vez se pueda usar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; 
cannot be cast to class [Lhashtables.NodoDoble; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; 
[Lhashtables.NodoDoble; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Para esto estoy usando las siguientes clases:

Clase Hash Table
Como se puede ver, estoy utilizando el metodo de encadenamiento para la resolución de mis colisiones.

```
public class HashTable <T extends Object> {
    
    private NodoDoble<T>[] tabla;
    int cont;
    double fc=0.7;
    
    public HashTable(){
        tabla= (NodoDoble<T>[]) new Object[100];
        cont=0;
    }
    
    public void insert(T elem){
        NodoDoble<T> actual=new NodoDoble(elem);
        int resp;
        
        if((cont+1)/tabla.length >fc)
            expande();
        
        resp=elem.hashCode();
        NodoDoble<T> cabeza = tabla[resp%tabla.length];

        actual.setDer(cabeza.getDer());
        actual.setIzq(cabeza);
        actual.getDer().setIzq(actual);
        cabeza.setDer(actual);
        
        cont++;
        
    }
    
    private void expande(){
        NodoDoble<T>[] tabla2=(NodoDoble<T>[])new Object[tabla.length*2];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < tabla2.length; i++) {//PARA EL CENTINELA
            tabla2[i]=new NodoDoble<T>(null);
        }
        
        NodoDoble<T> actual;
        NodoDoble<T>[] aux=tabla;
        
        tabla=tabla2;
        tabla2=aux;
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < tabla2.length; i++) {
            actual=tabla2[i].getDer();
            
            while(actual!=null){
                insert(actual.getElem());
            }
        }
        
    }
    

    
    private NodoDoble<T> search(T elem){
        int resp;
        NodoDoble<T> actual;
        
        resp=fnHash(elem);
        actual=tabla[resp%tabla.length];
        
        while(actual!=null && !actual.getElem().equals(elem))
            actual=actual.getDer();
        
        if(actual==null)
            return null;
        else
            return actual;
        
        
    }
    
    public T elimina(T elem){
        NodoDoble<T> actual=search(elem);
        
        if(actual!=null){
            actual.getIzq().setDer(actual.getDer());
            if(actual.getDer()!=null)
                actual.getDer().setIzq(actual.getIzq());
        }
        else
            return null;
        
        cont--;
        
        return elem;
    }
    
    public int fnHash(T elem){
        return elem.hashCode();
    }
    
}
```

Clase NodoDoble:

```
public class NodoDoble <T> {
    
    private NodoDoble<T> izq;
    private NodoDoble<T> der;
    private T elem;
    
    public NodoDoble(T elem){
        this.elem=elem;
        izq=null;
        der=null;
    }
    
    public void setIzq(NodoDoble<T> otro){
        izq=otro;
    }
    
    public void setDer(NodoDoble<T> otro){
        der=otro;
    }
    
    public NodoDoble<T> getDer(){
        return der;
    }
    
    public NodoDoble<T> getIzq(){
        return izq;
    }
    
    public T getElem(){
        return elem;
    }
}
```

El error me lo marca específicamente en esta lineal de la clase HashTable:

```
        tabla= (NodoDoble<T>[]) new Object[100];
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Todo extiende de Object, por lo que

```
        public class HashTable <T extends Object>
```

es una redundancia.

Por otro lado,

```
    tabla= (NodoDoble<T>[]) new Object[100];
```

¿Porqué no creas directamente el array del objeto para no necesitar casteo (que además lo estás haciendo al revés, instanciando  Object y casteando a NodoDouble, el casteo va en la otra dirección). Otra cosa es que instancies NodoDouble, castees a Objet y de nuevo a NodoDouble, en ese caso sí sería correcto)

Si no me equivoco sería así:

```
    tabla=new NodoDouble<T>[100];
```